# Touch Event Pressure in blackberry cascades

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

How to find touch event pressure in blackberry 10 cascades? Is there any API available for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: 
The native SDK has a structure called [mtouch_event](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/bb10/com.qnx.doc.inputevents.lib_ref/topic/structmtouch__event.html) which contains the width & height of the touch.But the docs state it is not implemented.Not sure if there's something similar in Cascades, or whether you can access the raw native mtouch_event data.